# why did sqlcmd -v foo="c:\path" eat the "c:"?

Tags: sql, cmd, sqlcmd

I have foo.sql as:

```
print 'foo=$(foo)'
```

Then I have in foo.cmd the following shell script:

```
sqlcmd -i foo.sql -v foo="c:\path"
```

Running foo.cmd prints:

```
foo=\path
```

how do I escape the "c:"?  Is dos-shell eating it, or is it sqlcmd?

Comment: Can't reproduce here. `echo print 'foo=$(foo)'>foo.sql & sqlcmd -i foo.sql -v foo="c:\path" -S .\SQLExpress` yields `foo=c:\path` as expected. Are you really sure you are using `cmd` as your shell?

Comment: I had the sqlcmd line in another shell batch file. Wonder if that makes any difference.

Comment: OK, my mistake. the above does work.  What i did wrong was doing:
sqlcmd -i foo.sql -v foo='c:\path'  (single quote, since I tried to pass them as ' ' sql string)  that won't work. it will chop the c:

Comment: Why would anything eat something?! It was hungry!  - Just kidding...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, my mistake. the above does work.

What i did wrong was doing: sqlcmd -i foo.sql -v foo='c:\path'

(single quote, since I tried to pass them as ' ' sql string) that won't work. it will chop the c:

Answer (score 1):

cmd's argument delimiters include the equal sign. I've seen in other cases (such as bjam.exe) that the entire parameter sequence has to be quoted to work properly.

Try this:

```
sqlcmd -i foo.sql -v "foo=c:\path"
```

If it still strips the "c:" portion, I'd focus on sqlcmd. I don't personally have it installed to test with. This is based solely on experience with similar situations.

Answer (score 0):

Using another shell causes this.

I just had this when running sqlcmd via powershell.  Switched to using cmd.exe and it worked fine

double quotes to escape the ":" and single quotes so that sql treated the variable value as a string.  e.g.

sqlcmd -S . -d myDb -i .\test.sql -v pathToFile = "'D:\Temp\temp\My.csv'"

Answer (score -2):

Escape the backslash,

```
sqlcmd -i foo.sql -v foo="c:\\path"
```

It's actually your shell eating the \

Comment: `cmd` doesn't even use `\\` as the escape character. How do you think it's supposed to interpret it as such?